# Terminator terminal fail to launch

Tags: terminator

For some reason my terminator terminal stopped working yesterday. This is the error I get when I try to run it:

```
/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py:87: Warning: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised
self.gnome_program = gnome.init(APP_NAME, APP_VERSION)
```

I have tried a remove and reinstall but that did nothing for the issue. A solution would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: and you're saying it doesn't start?

Comment: It does start. The terminal flashes for a split second and then immediately closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case commenting every line in `~/.config/terminator/config` fixed the problem.
It seems like newer version cannot understand old config.

It is also weird that even if you do `aptitude purge terminator` it leaves this config file ;/